# Unable to start eclipse from the start menu

Tags: eclipse

I know about -vm option, and requiring the correct 32/64 bit version of java with the corresponding version of eclipse to start.

I have spring tool suite btw.

However, I have a situation here, where:
I can start eclipse from the exe by double clicking on "sts.exe". 
I can create a shortcut to it by copying and pasting shortcut.
I can open this shortcut by double clicking on it.
But when i open this via the run command, it refuses to work saying:

Failed to load the JNI shared library "F:\Programs\SDKs\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll".

I have even entered the -vm option in the ini, but nothing seems to help. I just cant open it via the start menu!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a reboot, none of the options work. So was an obvious 32 bit vs 64bit error.

(Mods: Please feel free to close this question if required. It wont really contribute much)